# how to remove "incompatible function pointer types" warning when using the c-lib function qsort

Tags: c, clang, compiler-warnings, qsort

I'm trying to use the c-lib function qsort() to sort an array of longs. I do it as follows:

```
int
compar(long *e1, long *e2)   // for decreasing order
{
   if (*e1 > *e2) return -1;
   if (*e1 < *e2) return 1;
   return 0;
}

void
c_lib_quick_sort(long *a, long n)
{
   qsort(a, n, sizeof(long), compar);
}
```

The code works perfectly, but clang produces the following warning

```
sort_timings.c:262:30: warning: incompatible function pointer types passing 'int (long *, long *)' to parameter of type 'int (* _Nonnull)(const void *, const vo
id *)' [-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]
   qsort(a, n, sizeof(long), compar);
                             ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:161:22: note: passing argument to parameter '__compar' here
            int (* _Nonnull __compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

Can someone show me how to eliminate the warning? The warning refers to things like (* _Nonnull), which I've never seen before.

I wrote similar code 15 years ago, but gcc at the time did not produce any warnings. The newer compilers are more strict about types.

Comment: Try declaring the parameters of `compar` as `const void *` and then casting them to `const long *` inside.

Comment: See [Confused about Qsort and Pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670320/confused-about-qsort-and-pointers).

Comment: The `_Nonnull` is a hint to the compiler that the pointer is not supposed to be the null pointer, so it can give better optimizations and warnings.  You can ignore that part.

Answer (score 2):

The warning indicates what is the expected function signature

```
passing argument to parameter '__compar' here
            int (* _Nonnull __compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

So changing it accordingly, should help address the warnings:

```
int
compar(const void *p1, const void *p2)   // for decreasing order
{
    const long* e1 = (const long*)p1;
    const long* e2 = (const long*)p2;
    if (*e1 > *e2) return -1;
    if (*e1 < *e2) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```